# Joining a tree structure

Tags: postgresql

Table 1 (named as **family**) has a tree structure with 2 columns id and pathid, where pathid describes the tree structure. In the following table 1 is a root node with 2 as its child. 3 is a rootnode with 4 as a child and 5 is the child of 4(grandchild of 3). 6 is a rootnode with no children. 7 is a rootnode with 3 children 8, 9 and 10.

| id | pathid | parentid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | /1 |  |
| 2 | /1/2 | 1 |
| 3 | /3 |  |
| 4 | /3/4 | 3 |
| 5 | /3/4/5 | 4 |
| 6 | /6 |  |
| 7 | /7 |  |
| 8 | /7/8 | 7 |
| 9 | /7/9 | 7 |
| 10 | /7/10 | 7 |

Table 2 (named as **register**) has the name column and the id column.

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 6 |
| D | 7 |
| E | 4 |
| F | 10 |

Required result is name with all the family descendants only.

| name | all_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 6 |
| D | 7 |
| D | 8 |
| D | 9 |
| D | 10 |
| E | 4 |
| E | 5 |
| F | 10 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do. When you have an hierarchical structure with the "path" stored, it's often easier to use text comparisons, eg. `LIKE`:
(When the path is stored as text. If it is stored as an array, you'd use array operators).

```
SELECT
    r.name,
    fc.id AS all_id
FROM
    register AS r
    JOIN family AS fp
      ON r.id = fp.id
    JOIN family AS fc
      ON fc.pathid LIKE CONCAT(fp.pathid, '%')
ORDER BY
    r.name, r.id,
    fc.pathid ;
```